# What constitutes spam?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-answer

I was peeking at the first post review queue while eating lunch and noticed this answer: [What are the advantages of walk-in or in person interviews over online video interviews?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/44518/what-are-the-advantages-of-walk-in-or-in-person-interviews-over-online-video-int/44598#44598)

It looks like the company made an account just to draw attention to their product, however they never actually promote their product in the post... It leaves a little bit of a bad taste in my mouth but it does provide *some* information. If any random user had posted it (with no references to the company) I would pass it off as a mediocre answer and if they said "we do that, you should use us" it would be spam, but as it is, I'm just not sure...

Comment: I just edited out the sales pitchy stuff.

Comment: Ian, is your question specifically about that answer (which has now been edited), or are you asking a broader question about what counts as spam and that's just one example?  (Trying to decide if this is status-completed...)

Comment: Yeah it was about that one question, go ahead and status-complete it.

Answer (score 1):

Are companies permitted to register, and provide answers (rather than individuals)?

If so, I guess I'm surprised. I wouldn't have thought that would be allowed.

Comment: The developer of doxygen tool provides what is essentially customer support on StackOverflow through this account: http://stackoverflow.com/users/784672/doxygen, and nobody seems to have a problem with that. Unless the company account is actively promoting their products on unrelated questions, IMHO there shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @MaskedMan - sounds like good social media advertising. Again, I'm surprised.